# How to get Workrave indicator to show in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, workrave

How can I get the Workrave indicator to show in Ubuntu 17.10? [Version 1.10](http://www.workrave.org/blog/2013/01/13/workrave-110-released/) supposedly has GNOME Shell support.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It took some time to figure this out for me, too...

Before Ubuntu 20.04, you'll first need gnome-tweak-tool for being able to enable this.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later, the program called "Extensions" is installed by default.

Second, the Workrave package in the official repo is badly packaged (it brings down some XFCE dependencies that mess up your Gnome session), so you'll have to install the workrave-gnome package from Rob Caeler's PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:rob-caelers/workrave
```

Now you can do:

```
sudo apt install workrave-gnome
```

- Now fire up Workrave. It will show up in a small window with all the timers running -- no applet yet.
- Then fire up Extensions (< Ubuntu 20.04, fire up gnome-tweak-tool and head to Extensions), and enable Workrave.

Now the applet (and/or the tray icon, if you're using it) should be visible in the top panel.

One more thing I've noticed on my machine is that Workrave segfaults under Wayland, so you will probably have to login into xorg if you want to use Workrave.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I've filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/workrave/+bug/1726244 in hopes this'll be fixed.

Comment: The PPA now has an artful version, would you mind having a look at updating the instructions?

Comment: The other response (https://askubuntu.com/a/973972/50901) fixes the crash for me.

Comment: I can confirm this also works beautifully for Ubuntu 18.04.
Thanks so much for the answer @Franko!

Comment: This also works for me on 20.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was getting segfaults also but managed to get it to work by specifying the X window:

```
workrave --display=:0
```

To fix it permanently:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/workrave.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

And then edit the "Exec" command in ~/.local/share/applications/workrave.desktop

Comment: An interesting observation though. Mine was only crashing when prime-select was set to intel. It didn't crash under my nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 18.04, just [install "GNOME Tweaks"](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and in Extensions tab, turn on Workrave notification.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i don't have 'Workrave' extension in 18.04.

Comment: @atti reinstall workrave and reboot. Maybe help!

Comment: handling of GNOME Shell extensions has changed, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add command `workrave --display=:0` to Startup Applications.

Not sure why, but copying workrave.desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications/` and modifying it didn't work for me but Startup Applications did.