# Workrave applet in Extensions stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, startup-applications, workrave

I've been using Workrave on Ubuntu 22.04 for several years now; installed it following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/967425), activated the applet that shows timers in the top bar through Extensions, and added Workrave to my Startup Applications. All worked fine, until a few days ago, when I noticed that Workrave no longer started at startup. Somehow it had disappeared from my Startup Applications. Also, I can no longer activate the Workrave applet that shows timers in the top bar, in Extensions the toggle button is greyed out.

What happened, has something changed to Workrave, or to Ubuntu 22.04? Is there anything I can do to fix this (already tried updating, uninstall/re-install)?

Comment: perhaps contact the developer for support? https://workrave.org/support/

Comment: Good one @graham, I'll do that too. The reason I posted here is that Workrave also disappeared from my Startup Applications, this made me think that my issue might (in part) be related to some change in Ubuntu.

Comment: my experience with contacting developers direct has consistently been good...